# Showing adjacent div with hover using only CSS

Tags: html, css

I have two adjacent `divs`. One has only a single header ("MENU"). The second one is a simple table of contents. I want to show the table of contents iff user's screen width is >= 800px. In any other situation, the MENU `div` is hidden and table of contents is visible by default.

In order to show/hide table of contents based on screen size I use:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
  #tableOfContents  { display: none; }
  #menuSign { display: block}
```

I figured out how to show the table of contents when user hovers over MENU sign but I have no idea how to make it stay visible when the cursor moves from one div to the other.

```
#menuSign:hover + #tableOfContents {
    display: block; 
    background: #f00;
    cursor: default;
    background-color: darkgray;
    color: white;
    }
```

Sorry if the answer to my question is obvious- I'm completely new to web development. All answers to similar problems either used JS (which I cannot do) or did't explain how to make table of contents persist on the screen.

Comment: Please add some working HTML we can toy with. For now I'd say you have the CSS for 'IF ... THEN', you also need to think of CSS for 'ELSE' (as in 'what to do when max-width is not 800px')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the divs have no empty space between them and the cursor can flow seamlessly from one to the other, you might try to change the selector into:

```
#menuSign:hover + #tableOfContents, #tableOfContents:hover { display: block; }
```

Also, as a personal suggestion, you should try never to use IDs in your CSS, it's bad practice: https://dev.to/claireparker/reasons-not-to-use-ids-in-css-4ni4

Moreover, if you are attempting to create a simple hamburger navigation menu, it's better to show the menu itself when the user clicks on the button instead of just hovering over it, for consistency with devices that don't have the hover functionality like mobile phones. This can be achieved in a number of different ways, the simplest involving some very simple JavaScript (or [jQuery, for the simpler syntax](https://www.htmlgoodies.com/beyond/cms/creating-a-hamburger-menu-with-html-css-and-jquery.html)) to add or remove a class on the DOM parent of the elements you are attempting to style now, or with hacks like [using a checkbox as a proxy for the menu button](https://scotch.io/tutorials/building-a-morphing-hamburger-menu-with-css).

Comment: Using ID's has its uses, don't post opinions just because you read them somewhere and you tend to agree with them. And don't advice jQuery to a 'I'm completely new to web development' newbie, especially when they ask not to JS.

Comment: Thank you! Your solution is exactly what I was looking for. I know that creating a hidable menu using `hover` is not ideal, but it's one of the requirements for the project

Comment: @RenevanderLende Using IDs in CSS has no uses, and I say that having built a substantial number of websites in my career. Dealing with just 2 levels of specificity (element + class) and maximum 3 levels of overloading (e.g. `.Context .Element.Modifier`) makes everything much more flexible and easy to scale, while insuring there's no inflation anywhere in the design & maintenance life cycle. E.g. creating a complex, responsive interface element that can then be reusable anywhere is a remarkably useful trait, which makes the strategy entirely worthwhile. I agree with the jQuery comment...

Comment: @ViorelMocanu they are there, so they are usable. With billions of webpages we both can be right some of the time, but not all the time. I really am not into a discussion about this. HTML and CSS are means to a goal, not the goal itself (to me anyway).